# Linq value between 2 column ranges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i'm having a little difficulty creating the linq i need to replicate the below SQL statement.

```
    SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[Price]
      ,[ThicknessFrom]
      ,[ThicknessTo]
      ,[WeightFrom]
      ,[WeightTo]
  FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 
  WHERE (8 between [ThicknessFrom] and [ThicknessTo])
  AND (100 between [WeightFrom] and [WeightTo])
```

Example of the data i have:

```
id: 1, price: 1, thicknessFrom: 0, thicknessTo: 10, weightFrom: 0, weightTo: 125
id: 2, price: 2, thicknessFrom: 11, thicknessTo: 20, weightFrom: 126, weightTo: 250
```

i want to return the query from an above linq statement that would return data based on 2 inputs, weight and thickness which would return id = 1.

thanks

Comment: 8 between [ThicknessFrom] and [ThicknessTo] means  [ThicknessFrom] = 8 and  [ThicknessTo] = 8?

Comment: i've added some sample data to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyTable.Where(entities => entities.ThicknessFrom <= 8)
       .Where(entities => entities.ThicknessTo >= 8)
       .Where(entities => entities.WeightFrom <= 100)
       .Where(entities => entities.WeightTo >= 100)
       .Take(1000);
```

What we're doing above is chaining multiple predicates to keep things clean / easy to read, the query isn't actually executed until the `.Take()` method is executed.

Comment: thanks dude.  that has been bugging me for an hour! post xmas hangover coding is not good

Comment: SQL Between is **inclusive**.  Your code is exclusive.  Please change `<` to `<=` and `>` to `>=`.

Comment: @RichardSchneider ouch, that's rather embarrassing :\

Answer (score 1):

Let `inputThicknes` and `inputWeight` be the two inputs, then you can create the LINQ like the following, which will give you the required result:

```
var requiredCollection = (from t in db.MyTable where 
                               t.ThicknessFrom < inputThicknes  && 
                               t.ThicknessTo >= inputThicknes  &&
                               t.WeightFrom < inputWeight &&
                               t.WeightTo >= inputWeight
                          select t).Take(1000)
```

Comment: hey, that doesn't work.  thats like entering:

  SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[SamplePostPrices]
  where ([ThicknessFrom] > 8 and [ThicknessTo] < 8)
  and ([WeightFrom] > 100 and [WeightTo] < 100)

but i can only get the statement working using 'between'

Comment: I have few updates in the answer, by changing the comparison operators, if you don't mind please take a look